# Does a power-complete finite pasture exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, ring-theory, universal-algebra

Suppose we define a **pasture** to be an algebraic structure $\langle M, 0, +, \times, \wedge \rangle$ where

- $\langle M, 0, +, \times \rangle$ is a ring (not necessarily commutative or unital)
- $\wedge$ distributes over $\times$ on the left: $(a \times b) \wedge c = (a \wedge c) \times (b \wedge c)$
- $\wedge$ distributes $+$ into $\times$ on the right: $a \wedge (b + c) = (a \wedge b) \times (a \wedge c)$

The idea is that a pasture is a bit like a field (in that it consists of a ring with additional structure), but goes off in a slightly different direction (by adding exponentiation instead of division).

Now let's call $x \in M$ a **perfect power** if $x = y \wedge z$ for some $y, z \in M$. Moreover, let's say that $M$ is **power-complete** if all of its elements are perfect powers. For example, the trivial pasture $\{0\}$ is clearly power-complete.

> **Question:** Does a nontrivial power-complete finite pasture exist?

<s>I was inspired to ask this question after running a computer search for finite pastures and noticing that they tend to have few perfect powers. In fact, most of the pastures I found had a single perfect power, often (but not always) $0$. If my code is correct, then I have confirmed that no pasture of order $\le 8$ is power-complete, and moreover that no commutative unital pasture of order $\le 10$ is power-complete.</s>

Side note: for $2 \le n \le 10$, the number of non-isomorphic commutative unital pastures of order $n$ is given by $(2, 2, 10, 2, 4, 2, 36, 10, 4)$. This is not a sequence recognized by the OEIS.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to a comment by @user60589, I have discovered a bug in my code which invalidates the above results. In fact, there are plenty of examples of power-complete pastures of order $\le 10$.

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code? Has *meadow* been used in this sense before, or [are they](http://mathoverflow.net/a/3015/43499) [talking about something](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186171/the-prime-meadow-of-a-meadow) [different?](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0823v1.pdf) If not I suggest choosing a different name. Does a nontrivial *meadow* exist at all?

Comment: @flawr "Meadow" is just a name I had made up; I had no idea it had already been used for a different notion! I'll change it to "pasture"; hopefully this has not already been taken.

Comment: @flawr With regards to the code, what I wrote was actually an [input file containing the pasture axioms](http://pastebin.com/4tdPHGLP) for Andrej Bauer's excellent [Alg](http://math.andrej.com/alg/) program, which systematically searches for finite models of first-order theories.

Comment: @flawr Finally, to address existence, [here is the operation table of a pasture of order $8$ with four perfect powers](http://pastebin.com/KHUzxnDe). This is perhaps the "most nontrivial" of the pastures I've found so far, with $4$ perfect powers, but it does have the funny property that its $\wedge$ is constant with respect to its first argument. In fact, every pasture I've come across has this property, so they are all in some sense a little bit trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! It seems to be an interesting idea and I am trying to play around with it. But I fear that it might be not very interesting because would assume that this has been studied before.

Comment: Is there an obvious reason for not insisting that $z\neq 1$ in the definition of perfect power? I realize that stipulating $x\wedge 1 = x$ for all $x$ has far reaching consequences, but not precisely which.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf I also wanted to consider the case of pastures without a multiplicative identity. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Am I getting the definiton wrong or is $\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$ with the usual exponentiation power-complete since $x^1=x$? An other power-complete pasture would be a ring where all elements are idempotent with identity as power.

Comment: @user60589 For every value of n I've checked, there are subtle issues with exponentiation that prevent $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ from being a pasture. For example, in $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z}$, we have $2^{1+2} = 2^0 = 1$, while $2^1 \times 2^2 = 2$. I'm not sure I understand your second example--what do you mean when you say "identity as power"? Could you give the operation table of such a pasture?

Comment: @DavidZhang Ah, thanks, I did not checked it carefully. The second example it should work anyway take a ring where all elements are idempotent and then define $x^y=x$. This should be a pasture.

Comment: @user60589 Ah, you are right! I have just discovered an error in my code which caused me to miss this family of examples. I will gladly accept if you make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any ring $R$ in which all elements are idempotent there is a *trivial* pasture structure on $R$ defined via
$$ x^y =x $$
for all $x,y \in R$. The left distributivity with multiplication is trivial and the right distributivity with addition is equivalent to the fact that all elements are idempotent.

This pasture structure on $R$ is obviously power-complete.

So for instance for all natural numbers $n$
$$ (\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z} )^n $$
is a power-complete pasture.