# Can an algebraic field be redefined and an axiom added?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can an algebraic field be redefined to allow division by 0 and an axiom included to define x/0 as x(1/0)?

I was thinking of making a field, let's call it J for now, where numbers are written as a + bi + cj and j = 1/0. J would include complex numbers.

An axiom would also have to be added stating that 0j = 0 and that x(1/x) = 1 only if x =/= 0 or j, so that the multiplicative inverse property still applies to all other numbers.

0j couldn't be 1 because that would mean that (0 x 0)j = 0j = 1 and 0(0j) = 0 x 1 = 0; 0 = 1. But that problem doesn't exist if 0j = 0.

Other than that, operations in J would work like operations with complex numbers (associative property, distributive property, etc.). Is doing this allowed?

Would it be a simpler solution to simply say 1/0 = 0 and x/0 = x(1/0) = 0? An axiom would have to be added that states x/y = z --> x = yz only if y =/= 0. Would this solution be better than creating a new element j, or would it result in contradictions?

Comment: In math, things aren't "allowed" or "not allowed". No one forbids you from writing these things down. One can study what properties such a structure does or doesn't have and see whether it is useful for something.

Comment: Your modification would then not be a "field", but something else.  I do not recall the details, but there have been defined things like "meadow" that do allow $0^{-1}$ to be defined.  If you search "meadow" here you get some matches using "meadow" in this sense.  For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186171/the-prime-meadow-of-a-meadow

Comment: Can a field be part of a meadow? Because j numbers would include complex numbers, since they are written in the form a + bi + cj. Although I'm thinking about if it would be possible to simply say that 1/0 = 0 and that x/0 = x(1/0) = 0

Comment: Why is this question being down-voted? It looks to me as a sincere question, and OP has given his reasons for believing it to be true.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I don't know, but I noted that the OP is posting this question several times already, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457798/can-division-by-0-be-defined-by-setting-1-0-0), which is certainly not helpful.

Comment: I edited the question. It's related to the same problem but I'm trying to see if the other solution is simpler or if it has contradictions that the solution in this post doesn't have.

Comment: I'll just close the other question then and edit this one.

Comment: I've closed it and I've edited this question. Sorry if I gave the impression that I was duplicating the question because this one got down-voted. That wasn't the intention. The  2 questions simply asked about different approaches to the same problem. But I realize now it was better to just edit this question.

Comment: First, you need to ask yourself, why do you want the field definition to be extended or modified. Zero is already a special element in the field of reals, for instance, as it has no inverse. Are you trying to make it more special? What is the purpose of your changes?

Comment: The purpose of the change is to define division by 0 despite the fact that 0 has no inverse

Comment: @Acuna0730L Since division is defined as multiplying by an inverse, you cannot define division by zero without having multiplicative inverse for it.

Comment: What if we say division is multiplication by an inverse unless you are dividing by 0, and then the rule for division by 0 is different?

Answer (score 3):

**It is Self-Contradictory**

You want a field where $1/0$ is well-defined. In other words you want an element $j$ such that $0 j  = 1$.

For a start this contradicts your extra axiom that $0j = 0$. We cannot have both $0 j  = 0$ and $0 j  = 1$, as this implies $0=1$ which is false unless our field is the trivial field. (**Exercise**)

Let's forget about the extra axiom for the moment. Suppose as you say we have such a $j$. Now let $x,y$ be any two field elements. Since $0x = 0=0y$ we can write

$$ 0x = 0y \implies j0x =j0y \implies  (j0)x=(j0)y \implies x=y$$

Since any two elements are equal the field only has one unique element.
So even without assuming  $0j = 0$ we still are stuck with the trivial field.

Comment: In my question I said that an axiom would have to be added so that x(1/x) = 1 only if x =/= 0 or j. In other words, 0 x j =/= 1. Another axiom would have to be added that states that 0 j = 0. That way, we don't have the problem of x = y.

Comment: $0 \times j = 1$ is the definition of the inverse of $0$. If you want $0 \times j \ne 1$ then I have no clue what you mean by $1/0$.

Comment: 0 doesn't have an inverse and neither does j. I'm defining division by 0 without the use of a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Then what do you mean by $1/0$? You are of course free to have an element called $1/0$ but the problems arise when you start demanding it has properties.

Comment: j numbers have the same properties as complex numbers. To put an example, (a + bi + cj) + (a + bi + cj) = 2a + 2bi + 2cj.

Comment: @Acuna0730 Okay just define $1/0 = 0$.

Comment: No, 1/0 = j. j =/=0

Comment: If you want $j  \ne 0 $ then you cannot have a field. Because every nonzero field element has an inverse. You need to remove axioms rather than add them.

Comment: Can't the axiom be changed to every nonzero and non-j element has an inverse?

Comment: But maybe 1/0 = 0 would also work. Then we define x/0 as (1/0)x = 0, and j wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Acuna0730 One thing you can do is take any field, attach  a second zero element $0'$ say, define $1/0 = 0'$ and then define each $x+0' = x$ and $0'x = 0$. Though I am not sure this still satisfies the other field axioms. You should check it. It is also worth checking the same with $0'x =0'$ for all $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @Acuna0730 Actually this doesn't work as we have $0'+x= x = 0+x \implies 0'+x=0+x \implies 0'=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot be done**

The difficulty with adding an extra element to any algebraic structure is it might want to create other elements when you perform operations. For example given a ring $R$ you can add an extra element $x$ to get the polynomial ring $R[x]$ but this has loads of extra elements other than $x$ and things in $r$. Even if we demand $x^2 = x$ you still get the ring of formal sums $\{a+bx:a,b \in R\}$ which is much bigger than $R \cup \{x\}$.

To not get extra elements we need to define all sums and products so that $(1/0) + x$ and $x/0$ are already in the structure.

Suppose $(F,+,*)$ is a field. Then $(F,+)$ is a group. You want to add some element $a$ to get the set $F'=F \cup \{a\}$ such that $(F',+,*)$ is a ring and satisfies most of the field axioms. For example a commutative ring with exactly two non-invertible elements.

Then we at least want $(F',+)$ to be a group. This is a problem because $F$ is then a subgroup of $F'$. Hence the Lagrange theorem says $|F|$ divides $|F'| = |F|+1$. This can only happen if $|F|=1$ and we started with the trivial field.

It follows that no interesting ring is contained in a ring with exactly one more element. It doesn't matter what the extra element is called or what properties it has.

In fact there are very few rings with exactly two non-invertible elements at all! The proof is similar to the above and is left as an exercise.